# How to use a callback URL in twitter for sharing a content

Tags: java, android, twitter, mobile-application

I have a code for sharing a content with twitter,but it contains some field like OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL,OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME etc.How to use them and what URL should I put inside a CALLBACK_URL?
Link for my code...https://github.com/dhaval0122/Share_to_Facebook_twitter..
in this theirs a file called Constant.java,which has a variable named OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL,OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME,OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST.What Am I supposed to fill inside them?Plz reply..

Comment: Read the code comments carefully!!!

Comment: @Tirath Thanx for ur spontaneous reply......FYI I have been doin that since last 2 days...but still unable to crack it...plz could u..?

Comment: @Kiran : You do not have to edit the callback_host or scheme. Leave them as they are. You just need to replace your customer id and customer secret key which you will get once you register your app on dev.twitter.com/

Comment: @ArshadParwez Ya..I did it..but as Im clicking a login to twitter button in my application...It shows the following message in the logcat....oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Comment: You can try this link for using twitter and facebook share: http://arshad-parwez.blogspot.in/

Comment: @ArshadParwez Why Am I getting as...R cannot be resolved as a variable?..I dont even have any imports with respect to the R..but still I am getting this error..What should I do?

Comment: @ArshadParwez Also along with the above error Iam gettin as ..Unable to resolve target 'android-18'

Comment: @Kiran: You need to change the target to the latest Android SDK you have on your system. SDK level 18 is the latest Android 4.3.

Comment: @Kiran: Can you tell me where you getting the R cannot be resolved to a variable error.

Comment: @ArshadParwez I got rid of those "R" errors..but while Im trying the sample code for twitter suggested by you...and each time Iam trying to tweet....It shows me Tweet not sends....ie(its not tweeting)

Comment: @Kiran: Did you replace the Consumer key & consumer Secrete Key which is in the Constants.java file

Comment: @ArshadParwez Yes I replaced the consumer key and consumer sec. key......the error Im getting is...403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).

Comment: @Kiran : You are getting 403 error as you are sending the same tweet again and again. Please check your tweeter account on which you have posted. I believe it has been posted.

Comment: @ArshadParwez No ....I cannot see any posts on my behalf...not even a single one..

Comment: @Kiran: Have you added the "Read, Write and Access direct messages" in the Application Type on dev.twitter.com

Comment: @ArshadParwez Its showing a messge in orange color in logcat..TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ab8], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}

Comment: @Kiran : You need to type a message in the TextBox and then press the Tweet Status button.

Comment: @ArshadParwez I tried above all the methods you told but still getting the same toast.....Tweet not sent..

Comment: @Kiran : Please check you device date & time. Sometimes, it also causes problem, it must be correct according to the time standard of that country. Please paste your logcat , i want to see the error in full.

Comment: @ArshadParwez my date and timings are correct....How can I paste my logcat here itz..to long to be pasted?

Comment: Only the main about 10-15 lines logcat which contains the error part.

Comment: @ArshidParwez 08-26 18:02:06.489: W/ResponseProcessCookies(3405): Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A137752032578030472; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 26-Aug-2015 12:32:06 UTC". Unable to parse expires attribute: Wed, 26-Aug-2015 12:32:06 UTC
08-26 18:02:07.399: D/error dj-->(3405): Access control configuration prevents your request from
08-26 18:02:07.399: D/error dj-->(3405): being allowed at this time.  Please contact your service provider if
08-26 18:02:07.399: D/error dj-->(3405): you feel this is incorrect.

Comment: 08-26 18:05:27.299: W/System.err(3331): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
08-26 18:05:27.369: W/System.err(3331): Access Denied
08-26 18:05:27.409: W/System.err(3331): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ab8], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}

Comment: The logcat states that you have Access Control permissions. Please check your App settings on dev.twitter.com and once try to reset the ur consumer key and consumer secret key. Then copy those in your Contants.java file

Comment: @ArshadParwez I have given all the three permissions REad,Write and message..still getting the error

Comment: @Kiran: I have checked in my app, this error is shown in my log if I do not enter any text in the textbox. Please enter any text in the textbox " Enter Text to Tweet".

Comment: @kiran: you wont see the text as the text color is black & the background color is also black. It was my mistake.

Comment: @ArshadParwez Nope....each time I type a text in " Enter Text to Tweet"..then press the tweet button.....It shows sending tweet.....but then gives a toast as tweet not posted

Comment: @Kiran: Ok just open the "res" folder -> "layout" folder -> "sending_tweet.xml" file. In this file edit the line no. 49 and replace it with android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

Comment: @ArshadParwez. still doesnt works

Comment: @Kiran: That was just to change the color of the text. Now when you type the text in the textbox, you can see it in Grey color.

Comment: @Kiran: Now tell me what all changes you made in the project code which you downloaded.